# display emoji in Java (jFrame)

Tags: java, iphone, csv, jframe, emoji

I have a csv file imported from iPhone and included Emoji smiles

Using iPhone the file looks like

[image]

But if I use open the csv file from computer

[image]

How can I process these characters in Java to get emoji smiles?

and when I change the extension to `.txt`

that what I get:

[image]

How can I display the original (iPhone) emoji? If I cannot do it, so how can I display the smiles like the `.txt` file?

each csv file has different emoji smiles!

Comment: Let me guess; you use Excel to open the CSV

Comment: yes!, even if I open the file using notepad, how can I display them in java!

Comment: See my answer; it is quite long but it will probably help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first: what is an "emoji"?

It is a code point in the ["emoticons" Unicode block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/index.htm). You will note that this block is outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), since all code points for this block are greater than U+FFFF.

Second point: how are they treated by your display?

It all depends on your display's capabilities, and post treatment. By "capabilities", it is understood that your font may, or many not have, a grapheme for such code points. By "post treatment", it is understood that the program may treat such code points differently.

In the iPhone display example, it recognizes the code points and substitutes them for images. In the text editor example, it uses a font which has a grapheme for these code points.

Third point: why does Excel display such crap whereas the font appears to have graphemes for these code points?

It is because of a longstanding bug in Excel which has never been fixed: it always supposes that CSV files are encoded with windows-1252 instead of UTF-8; it will only treat them as UTF-8 if the first code point in the file is a [byte order mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm).

---

OK, with all these in mind, the questions:

> how can I process these characters in Java to get emoji smiles ?

You don't need to do anything special; just open the file *with the correct character set* (that will be `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` or, if you're unlucky enough to not use Java 7+, `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`); then display the contents as text.

Well, of course, the font used needs to have graphemes for emoticons, see above.

> how can i display the original ( iPhone ) emoji?

You will need to "post treat" the character stream input, recognize emoticons and substitute images for them. And there's a catch here: a `char` in Java is 16 bits only, therefore two `char`s are needed to encode a smiley.

This will therefore not be an easy task; it is possible but not easy. Fortunately, starting with Java 8, you can use [`.codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) (reminder: `String` implements `CharSequence`) which will return an `IntStream` of code points into the string; sample code:

```
public final class Foo {

    // Same signature as an IntComsumer...
    private static void handleCodePoint(final int codePoint)
    {
        if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codePoint).equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS)) {
            // treat as an emoticon
        } else {
            // treat as non emoticon
        }
    }

    // ...

    public void doDisplay(final String input)
    {
        // ... therefore usable in an IntStream's .forEach()
        input.codePoints().forEach(Foo::handleCodePoint);
    }
}
```

If you use Java 7 or less, uh, it's still possible but much harder...

Comment: I think this is harder than i thought!, I am using java 7 update 71, I check this website http://www.journaldev.com/867/how-to-read-file-in-java-using-bufferedreader-scanner-files-with-encoding-support-and-filereader
and run the code, this is what i got ( Line1: ًںک„ Test ًںکک
line2: ? Test ?
line3: ? Test ?
line4: ًںک„ Test ًںکک

couldn't display the emoji like example3 ( notepad)

Comment: It appears to me that you don't use the correct charset when opening the file. Since you use Java 7, remember to use the new java.nio.file API instead of `File`.

Comment: can you please give me an example

Comment: An example of what exactly? How do you open your file for reading at the moment,

Comment: an example of java,nio.file, 
File file = new File("file.txt");FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

Comment: And there lies your error: you don't specify the charset when you open the file for reading; do `final Path path = Paths.get("file.txt"); final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: thank you fge, the result is: ? Test ?, I still have "?" instead of the smiles!

Comment: There is another problem then: the font used does not seem to have support for these code points. Try and run it in your IDE, and show the code you use as well